# I've just had a cup: is it correct?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

Is it correct to say like this?

> "Would you like some tea?"
>
> "Thank you, but I've just ***had a cup***"

Would it be more idiomatic to say ***had one***?
Or both options are wrong? If so, how would you answer in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep! That's perfect!

> Thank you, but I've just had a cup.

Is just right.

You could also say:

> Thanks but I've just had some.

You would not want to say (from the point of view of an AmE speaker):

> Thank you but I just had one.

The other person asked you if you wanted **some** tea, so it would be slightly odd (though not horribly so) to say "one".

If, however, the person had asked:

> Would you like a cup of tea?

Then, "Thanks, but I've just had one." would be great!

Comment: @Josh61 Yes... or that, though some cultures don't like saying "no", so I was trying to keep with the OP's wording.

Comment: +1. Nicely done. I was seeing if you missed anything. You didn't.